# DXA 1.2 exception Cannot create an abstract class on MediaItem

Tags: dxa

I am testing testing DXA .NET 1.2, when rendering a Component with a MediaItem, I get the exception:

> Cannot create an abstract class the modelType. the value is:
>
> modelType  {Name = "MediaItem" FullName = "Sdl.Web.Common.Models.MediaItem"}   System.Type {System.RuntimeType}

My `site.log` shows the following error:

> Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: Unable to map field 'media' to property of type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.MediaItem'.

code from `dxa-web-application-dotnet/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Mapping/DefaultModelBuilder.cs`

```
model = (ViewModel)Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);
```

FULL log:

015-12-04 18:39:39,553 [17] ERROR - Unable to map field 'media' to property of type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.MediaItem'.
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: Unable to map field 'media' to property of type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.MediaItem'. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.CreateViewModel(MappingData mappingData) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 389
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel& entityModel, IComponent component, Type baseModelType, Localization localization) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 202
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.CreateEntityModel(IComponent component, Type baseModelType, Localization localization) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\ModelBuilderPipeline.cs:line 119
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.MapComponent(IComponent component, Type modelType, Localization localization) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 737
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.MapFieldValues(IField field, Type modelType, Boolean multival, MappingData mapData) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 609
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.BaseController.EnrichModel(ViewModel model) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\BaseController.cs:line 84
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.EntityController.Entity(EntityModel entity, Int32 containerSize) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Controllers\EntityController.cs:line 18
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Comment: Did you check this out? http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13003/creating-custom-media-items-in-dxa-1-1

Comment: hi Bart, i checked the thread, i am not creating a custom media item, i use core Teaser and the site complains for Unable to map field 'media' to property of type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.MediaItem'. i am trying to inject DXA into an existing blueprint.

Comment: Hi Eric ;-).  Even though your scenario is different, I recommend the same analysis technique: ensure that warnings are logged and check the DXA site log. It should tell you more what the issue is: either it can't resolve any concrete type, or it resolves multiple (so it's ambiguous). In both cases it falls back to the model type (which is not a good idea in this case, because the model type is abstract)